# Master Pages in Java - JDK 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, master-pages

I am building a website in Eclipse Helios using Google App Engine and want to implement ASP.NET Master Page like functionality for common code across different pages. Is there something similar in Java?

Updated:
I am not a Java developor, after looking at the links in the posted answers, I think Facelets and Tiles Framework offer the template functionality. Which one is the preferred one? Both can run on GAE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with asp.net but a short read on master pages suggest to me that what you are looking for is JSF Facelets. Facelets allows you to define a template with default content and points where template clients can insert there code.

Template clients can fill in these insert points but don't have to fill in all of them or they can add new ones. So you can also build templates on other templates.

[Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu2/index.html) is an article which should you give a better idea of what JSF templating can do.

Instructions for setting up JSF on GAE are [here](https://sites.google.com/a/wildstartech.com/adventures-in-java/Java-Platform-Enterprise-Edition/JavaServer-Faces/sun-javaserver-faces-reference-implementation/configuring-jsf-20-to-run-on-the-google-appengine)

Comment: +1: Do you have a working link to download the Facelets framework? Which one would be simple to implement and use, Facelets or Tiles?

Comment: I would go for Facelets. Tiles mainly works with JSP, which is a little old-fashioned.

Comment: @A9S6, facelets is part of JSF or do you mean the JSF framework, I see it has moved to http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. I downloaded the binaries for JSF, will play around with it. I hope it won't be too complex to integrate Facelets into my Java web app.

Comment: @A9S6 If your new to Java EE it can be overwhelming it might help to do a test project in netbeans first as JSF should work "out of the box" with netbeans and the netbeans site has plenty of tutorials. http://www.netbeans.org/

Comment: JSF with Facelets, JSP,Java is better choice and one should try it for new applications medium to large complex.
You can use tiles if existing platform/Infra contains struts 1.x, some version of struts  with tiles.

Comment: Many times one can't compare Master pages equivalent in JAVA. Java developers use one of the java frameworks like struts,spring, spring MVC, apache my faces.  It is also proven that there are small to large successful projects without frameworks that enables you develop some thing in java analogous to  .Net Master pages, in such case developers use jsp,servlet combination to suite their project specific needs.

Comment: I am experienced with ASP.NET Master Pages, and when checked the corresponding options in Java/Eclipse world, it seemed much more complex when compared to .NET/VS world. Is my finding correct?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about GAE but here's [an SO question that has suggestions for Java EE applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532/asp-net-master-pages-equivalent-in-java).

**Update**

Here's a [list of stuff supported in GAE](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava) and [according to this SO answer, it seems to support certain versions of JSF as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732565/can-i-use-facelets-in-a-google-app-engine-app).